# How to setup a multi-tenant connection in NestJS with Typeorm

Tags: mysql, connection, nestjs, typeorm, multi-tenant

I'm working on an application with a multi-tenant architecture (on MySQL) where we have a database with multiples schemas which are composed with some tables. Is there a way to create a simple connection with [TypeOrm](https://typeorm.io/) where I can connect to any available schema from my database?
The documentation doesn't really talk about multi-tenancy so maybe it's impossible to do it with an easy approach?

Comment: You can create separate instances of Sequelize connection and register models for a certain schema there if it's what you really want

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Manage to got it working by creating a connection with the schema name on database option, then we can reuse this connection for later requests:

```
        const connectionName = `${db_schema_name}_connection`;
        try{
            return getConnection(connectionName);
        } catch(e){
            const options       = Object.assign({} , this.configService.get('DB_INFOS'));            
            options.name        = connectionName;
            options.database    = `yourdb_${db_schema_name}`;
        
            return await createConnection(options);
        }
```